# PATCH request not recognised by Marvin.JsonPatch

Tags: c#, json-patch

I'm trying to send an AJAX PATCH request to a Web API method and have the patched object recognised by [Marvin.JsonPatch](https://github.com/KevinDockx/JsonPatch).

So far, everything I've sent to the server has resulted in an empty request being received.

The Web API controller method looks like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Update(long orderId, JsonPatchDocument<Order> patchedOrder)
```

I'm POSTing using an `HttpClient` like this (can't use `async` in this application)...

```
var patchDoc = new JsonPatchDocument<Order>();
patchDoc.Replace(e => e.Price, newPrice);
patchDoc.Replace(e => e.WordCount, newWordCount);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), uri)
              {
                  Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc),
                                              System.Text.Encoding.Unicode,
                                              "application/json")
              };

HttpResponseMessage response;
using (var client = new HttpClient(...))
{
    response = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

But when the controller is it, the `patchedOrder` argument is `null`.

While debugging on the controller I've also tried

```
var s = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But this returns an empty string - can anyone explain why?

**UPDATE:**
This is what the contents of the JsonPatch document look like when passed in to the HttpClient...

```
{
    "Operations": [{
        "OperationType": 2,
        "value": 138.7,
        "path": "/price",
        "op": "replace"
    },
    {
        "OperationType": 2,
        "value": 1320,
        "path": "/wordcount",
        "op": "replace"
    }],
    "ContractResolver": {
        "DynamicCodeGeneration": true,
        "DefaultMembersSearchFlags": 20,
        "SerializeCompilerGeneratedMembers": false,
        "IgnoreSerializableInterface": false,
        "IgnoreSerializableAttribute": true,
        "NamingStrategy": null
    },
    "CaseTransformType": 0
}
```

Comment: Does `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc)` look like a JSON patch document?

Comment: @CodeCaster I've added the serialized content to the OP.

Comment: Well that's not good. Update your packages (at least Marvin.JsonPatch and Newtonsoft.Json) to the latest versions. There should be a custom serializer on the `JsonPatchDocument<T>` which writes only the operations, not the entire object.

Comment: I _was_ using Marvin.JsonPatch v2.1 but this had the same problem, so I downgraded to v1.1 as this is what is referenced in the WebAPI project, but obviously the problem persisted. Now that I've reverted to v2.1 it's still there but I can call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc.Operations)` and this works.  If you put your last comment as an answer then I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere during the development of Marvin.JsonPatch, the `JsonPatchDocument<T>` was annotated with an attribute that applied a custom JSON serializer:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPatchDocumentConverter))]
```

[This converter](https://github.com/KevinDockx/JsonPatch/blob/master/src/Marvin.JsonPatch/Converters/JsonPatchDocumentConverter.cs#L67) enables you to call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` on such a patch document and actually generate a patch document, as opposed to a representation of the `JsonPatchDocument<T>` CLR object.

Upgrade Marvin.JsonPatch and Newtonsoft.Json to the latest verison, and serialization should succeed.

Comment: This didn't work for me - I decorated the `Order` object with that `JsonConverter` attribute but I still receive `null`. It looks like that custom serializer produces an object with an 'Operations' property (which contains an array of operations), _i.e._ `{"Operations":[{"OperationType":2, ...` , whereas what works for me is serializing simply the operations themselves, _i.e._, `JsonConvert.Serialize(patchDoc.Operations)`.

Comment: My point is that with the latest Marvin.JsonPatch, your `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc)` should internally serialize only `patchDoc.Operations`... If it doesn't, then something else is amiss.